# why doesn't the else shown in code not work in this situation?

Tags: python

else near the bottom of the code doesn't work at all. It posts the error "File "main.py", line 35
    else:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

```
print("Numbers Inputted:", ages) #provides the user input into a list Form
x = input("Would You like to Delete the fifth number on your list? [yes/no]") #input for whethor or not the user wants to delete the fifth number on the list 
if x == 'yes':
 del ages[4] #deletes fourth line of code because i is +1
else: #if another input is inputted 
 print("Ages Given After Deletion or after remove option has been given", ages) #prints ages after the user has choosen to change the ages/numbers or not

y = input("Would you like to add a number onto your list? [yes/no]") #question for addition of a number
if y == 'yes': 
 for i in range (1): 
   e = float(input("enter the age that you would like to add:  ".format(i+1)))
ages.append(e)
else: 
 print("Calculating Results...") #print statement to provide seperation between calculations and user input 
print("min: ", min(ages)) #Prints min of ages using command
print("max: ", max(ages)) #prints max of ages using command  
print("sum: ", sum(ages)) #prints sum of ages using command 
print("average: ", sum(ages)/len(ages)) #prints average of given ages by diving sum by total inputs given 
s_ages = sorted(ages) #sorts list from highest to lowest
print('Ages From Lowest To highest', s_ages) #prints sorted list
counter=collections.Counter(ages) #gives frequency of user inputs
print("Frequency: [number inputted by user is on the left, while the amount of times that number was inputted in total is on the right...]", counter.most_common(5))
#provides specificity of output and prints frequency as well
```

Comment: Python is sensitive to indentation. Could you please fix it in your code? If it is fine, then if you can paste a formatted copy of the code it will be easier to debug.
Also, are you familiar with the debugger tool?

Comment: @perennial_noob I'm not familiar with the debugger tool.

Comment: Indentation preferences are personal, but Python has an official style guide that recommends _four spaces_. You don't _have_ to follow it, and lots of people prefer other styles (e.g. two spaces, tabs), but single spaces are one of the strangest and hardest to read choices I've come across. _Please_ don't write real code like this. (Also, a bit more whitespace would help.)

Comment: In addition to marking the accepted answer, @JohnSocaciu could you also upvote the answer so it is relevant and stays in the top?

Comment: @perennial_noob OP can't upvote yet, 15 reputation points are needed for upvote privilege.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the format of the code you pasted above is exactly how it is in your test, the immediate problem is:

```
if y == 'yes': 
   for i in range (1): 
      e = float(input("enter the age that you would like to add:  ".format(i+1)))
ages.append(e) #<--- this line indicates to Python that your `if` is all there is.
else: #<--- this is considered as an `else` without an `if`. That is the problem
   <rest of the code>
```

Judging the intent of the code, what you are looking for is to put the `ages.append(e)` withing the `for` like this:

```
if y == 'yes': 
   for i in range (1): 
      e = float(input("enter the age that you would like to add:  ".format(i+1)))
      ages.append(e) #<--- this line indicates to Python that your `if` is all there is.
else: #<--- this is considered as an `else` without an `if`. That is the problem
   <rest of the code>
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error you're getting is because the the line before the `else` is on the same indentation level as the `else` is. That unindented statement ended the previous block, so now the `else` has no `if` to be associated with.

It's not clear to me exactly what the correct indentation would be. It's either:

```
if y == 'yes': 
 for i in range (1): 
   e = float(input(...))
 ages.append(e)  # indent this the same as the for?
else:
 ...
```

Or:

```
if y == 'yes': 
 for i in range (1): 
   e = float(input(...))
   ages.append(e)  # or further?
else:
 ...
```

Note that your very shallow indentation is one of the reasons this issue might not have been obvious to you. Using more spaces per level (four is by far the most common) would make it much clearer. And be consistent! Your current code indents by one space some of the time, and by two spaces other times. That's a recipe for confusion.